# "The coordinates of the range are outside the dimensions of the sheet." error when sorting

Tags: javascript, excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a script to sort and then get some stat from an active CSV extension sheet/tab but I get an error that I couldn't identify. I keep getting the following message: Range coordinates are outside the sheet dimensions. My file contains data only in column A. The data consists of ID numbers and names. It does not contain any formulas. What am I doing wrong with my script?

NB: According to the error the problem comes from the line

> var pivotValue = pivotTable1.addPivotValue(2, SpreadsheetApp.PivotTableSummarizeFunction.COUNT)

.

Thanks for your help !

```
// TDC1  
  var pivotTable1 = syntheseSheet.getRange('A3').createPivotTable(sourceData);
  var pivotValue = pivotTable1.addPivotValue(2, SpreadsheetApp.PivotTableSummarizeFunction.COUNT);//Ligne
  pivotValue.setDisplayName('Nbre de LIGNES');
  var pivotGroup = pivotTable1.addRowGroup(16);
 
// TDC2
// sourceData = refSheet.getRange('1:'+nbr);
 syntheseSheet.setHiddenGridlines(true);
 var pivotTable2 = syntheseSheet.getRange('D3').createPivotTable(sourceData);
 pivotValue = pivotTable2.addPivotValue(6, SpreadsheetApp.PivotTableSummarizeFunction.COUNTUNIQUE);//REF
 pivotValue.setDisplayName('Nbre de Ref');
 pivotGroup = pivotTable2.addRowGroup(16); // agtPlanning
```

Comment: Can you provide a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on, free of sensitive information?

Comment: Sorry for the delay I had to filter the information
you can find the file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nNvi_CHWS4m7eJgWKSGIgqnRwB4yKLMr/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you provide the code related to `sourceData`? What does `syntheseSheet` refer to? It's not the same as the `CSV` converted to Sheets, right? It's a sheet from a regular spreadsheet?

Comment: Thanks for your answer I put the relative code or the whole function on [here] (https://script.google.com/d/1-KqWRopbCp2jOkcKsVwZ3UPdYA6MDit9s7menY6R27ki7DTNPNvkP8rJ/edit?usp=sharing)  and the second files is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1e1KfEhEc1s8O81bqk6ZwPNU5FmV6z7Qu/view?usp=sharing)
Basically, syntheseSheet is obtained by merging two CSV files which is in a folder called "Source File" on my drive.

Comment: Well, can you provide a copy of the spreadsheet containing `syntheseSheet`?

Comment: Of course, [clic here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11h7HP6DQFLLLfQhEq1mtbexkQ_rsafNs/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @lamblichus are you there? were you able to find something that could help me to see a little more clearly?

Comment: Hi! I'm sorry, I could not understand your current situation and your desired outcome based on the information you provided (not sure what data in the spreadsheet should be used, how it should be handled, and also the code you provided is extremely long, so I don't know where to look). If you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) maybe people will be able to help you.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the advice I will do it and post it later.  @lamblichus

Comment: Hello @lamblichus, finally I found the problem
I ended up running the macro again block by block and I found it.
As read on several forums, the problem was not coming from the line indicated by the Script Editor. 
It came from some line above (hard to show where, you know the code is long :)!

Thanks for your time and help.